# Править и/или редактировать?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, локализация

В истории правок обратил внимание на названия резолюций:

[image: править и редактировать]

Вроде  как "Править" это то же самое, что "редактировать", но почему-то используются разные слова. Может стоит выбрать что-то одно?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Я за краткие надписи:

- Править
- Отклонить и (ис)править

Краткость здесь важна и по той причине, что ссылка "править" есть под каждым сообщением, и там уже тесновато. Если разводить единообразие, то разумно выбрать короткое слово.