# Редактировать или править [метки]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, метки

В модераторских инструментах (10k+ реп) есть возможность быстрой правки меток вопроса. Называется всё это "редактировать метки":

> [image: редактировать метки]

Предлагаю для единообразия с [принятым решением](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3411/176217) и лаконичности переименовать этот пункт в "править метки".

Comment: Поздравляю с получением Сократа :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin мета-сократ :) его надо было бы назвать "сТократ".

Comment: Хмм, а неплохая идея! Люблю игру слов.

Comment: А я вот получил Мьелльнир по [meta-tag:обсуждение], теперь жду, когда можно будет жахнуть. ))

Comment: @NickVolynkin я вижу у Вас золотой за [Обсуждение](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/116/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5). А не за "предложение". Кстати, ещё и ссылка должна быть на мета-тег.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Изменил перевод на:

> [править метки](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40261585?key=dc23509a771572e18e0c7addfac2f03c)

И текст подсказки на

> [редактировать только метки вопроса](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40261583?key=a1548c1e3b872d0f72f2ef1d0360a828)

Будет доступно после подкачки transifex и сборки сайта.

Comment: Ещё "только" выпили оттуда. А то как-то странно звучит. И неужели кто-то может подумать, что это поле изменит метки всем вопросам сайта??

Comment: @Qwertiy немного переформулировал. Там в оригинале `edit only this question's tags`. Т.е. несколько иной смысл, нежели был у предыдущего перевода.